# SQL stored procedure to add up values and stop once the maximum has been reached

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I would like to write a SQL query (SQL Server) that will return rows (in a given order) but only up to a given total. My client has paid me a given amount, and I want to return only those rows that are <= to that amount.

For example, if the client paid me $370, and the data in the table is

```
 id amount
 1  100
 2  122
 3  134
 4  23
 5  200
```

then I would like to return only rows 1, 2 and 3

This needs to be efficient, since there will be thousands of rows, so a for loop would not be ideal, I guess. Or is SQL Server efficient enough to optimise a stored proc with for loops?

Thanks in advance.  Jim.

Comment: I have a suspicion that this is one of the few scenarios where a row-by-row, cursor approach will be faster than a set based approach...

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? If not 2012, do you have the ability to move to it since it is about to be released?

Comment: is the id to be used for order?  you may be able to use a LAG function.

Comment: @Randy - Not available until Denali (as with other `OVER` clause enhancements that will benefit running totals queries). `@jim` typically what proportion of the rows (meeting any where clause) will be returned and what proportion ignored?

Comment: thanks all for the assistance.  @Randy, most of the rows will be returned.  srutzky, we are on SQL2005, about to go to SQL2008.  No plans for SQL2012 at this stage.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options are.

1) Triangular Join

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable Y1
 WHERE (SELECT SUM(amount) 
        FROM YourTable Y2
        WHERE Y1.id >= Y2.id ) <= 370
```

2) Recursive CTE

```
WITH    RecursiveCTE
AS      (
        SELECT TOP 1 id, amount, CAST(amount AS BIGINT) AS Total
        FROM YourTable
        ORDER BY id
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  R.id, R.amount, R.Total
        FROM    (
                SELECT  T.*,
                        T.amount + Total AS Total,
                        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.id)
                FROM    YourTable T
                JOIN    RecursiveCTE R
                        ON  R.id < T.id
                ) R
        WHERE   R.rn = 1 AND Total <= 370
        )
SELECT  id, amount, Total
FROM    RecursiveCTE
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The 2nd one will likely perform better.

In SQL Server 2012 you will be able to so something like

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT id, 
       amount,
       SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id  
                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS RunningTotal
  FROM YourTable 
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM CTE
  WHERE RunningTotal <=370
```

Though there will probably be a more efficient way (to stop the scan as soon as the total is reached)

Comment: option 1 works well, and performs well enough fr me at this stage.  thanks heaps.

Comment: Here is my evental SQL.  Note that the additional 'where' elements in te sub-select clause improved performance, and the "top 100" ensured it did not run for too long.


    SELECT     TOP 100 PerfSearchID, userID, totalPrice
    FROM         PerformedSearches AS P1
    WHERE     (userID = 210) AND (totalPrice <> 0) AND
                              ((SELECT     SUM(totalPrice) AS Expr1
                                  FROM         PerformedSearches AS P2
                                  WHERE     (userID = 210) AND (totalPrice <> 0) AND (P1.PerfSearchID >= PerfSearchID)) <= 370)

Comment: This has been my first experience with stackoverflow.com and it's be marvelous!

Answer (score 0):

Straight-forward approach :

```
SELECT a.id, a.amount
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON (b.id <=a.id)
GROUP BY a.id, a.amount
HAVING SUM(b.amount) <= 370
```

Unfortunately, it has N^2 performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
select id from 
(
select t1.id, t1.amount, sum( t2.amount ) s 
from tst t1, tst t2
where t2.id <= t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.amount
) 
where s < 370
```